# django authentication always none, check_password works fine

Tags: django

after upgrading my django installation from 1.2.3 to 1.4 i can no longer use the `authenticate()` method.

The `check_password()` function works fine however, and i can see the encrypted password in the correct table in the database.

```
>>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> u = User(username='joe', password='password')
>>> u.set_password('password')
>>> u.save()
>>> from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
>>> user = authenticate(username='joe', password='password')
>>> user # this is None
>>> u.check_password('password')
>>> True
>>> u.check_password('passwordxxxx')
>>> False
```

my auth backends are normal.. and in experimenting i added specifically:

```
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = ('django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',)
```

which is the default i believe.

i'm at a loss as to how i can see where the problem is.. any ideas ?

cheers

-i

Comment: do you use any custom authentication backends?

Comment: hi Hoff.. no, edited the question to include more info

Comment: how embarrassing.. 

my machine crashed for a different reason and after a restart executing the above code works.

apologies Hoff ! :|.. i'll mark the question answered tomorrow (not allowed right now)

Comment: Just about to suggest a reload!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

bogus question, the above code works fine.